# Javascript escape characters not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

So my code is as below

```
`message.channel.send(
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'your bot token here';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
// If message content = .ping
if (message.content === '.ping') {
message.channel.send(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
}
});
client.login(token); 
);`
```

And I would like to put that into a string, However when attempting to im meant with a million syntax errors and so I googled escape character. I found the Javascript ones however when trying them the

```
message.channel.send(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
    }
```

ends up stopping the code with an unexpected identifier, When doing this without the above code it works.
If someone could hlep with formmating it, that would be great

P.S Im using Discord.js an addon for Node.js

Comment: Are you shure your nodejs supports template literals?

Comment: There's still just regular concatenation, did you try that ?

Comment: You appear to have a template literal inside a template literal. Your entire code block is wrapped in backticks. Is that correct, or a mistaken attempt at formatting?

Comment: You also have `const` where a function argument is expected, which is...odd. You open with `message.channel.send(` and follow it with `const Discord = require('discord.js');` ???

Comment: @Griffin: Stack Overflow is a very active place, even on the weekend. When you post a question (or an answer), *stick around* for a few minutes so you can address queries about your question/answer such as the ones above.

Comment: Also, in your template literal, you use the undefined variable `m`. You can't just go around copying code snippets from different places expecting them to work in harmony. Maybe seek some help at the [official discord.js server](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9). I'm sure they have questions like this every day which are easily solvable.

Comment: HI, everyone, Sorry for not responding quick first time here.
Jonasw Im sure it supports template literals
T.J.Crowder Its a mistake with formatting, First time here :P
@Cyingo Sorry for the m. I forgot to change it to message. 
This isn't code to run in by script. Its sending a message with that snippet of code, I simply forgot to add.
This only happens when the `message.channel.send(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);`
is in itt

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing us with the error you're getting there could be a few things going on, but I've got a vague Idea of what you're mistake is. You're trying to calculate the difference of time between a received message and a *not yet created* message.

What you want to do is reply to the message simply with some dummy text, say `ping`, then update that message and calculate the difference between the received message and your reply. Something like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'your bot token here';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  // If message content = ping
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('Pong!')
      .then(pongMessage => {
        pongMessage.edit(`Pong! Latency is ${pongMessage.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
      });
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

Your comment about this script, that it's not supposed to be run confused me a little bit, but if this is supposed to be one huge template literal you're sending and the `${}` is mistakenly interpreted as code, simply escape it with `\`

```
console.log(`${ 1 + 1 } | \${ 1 + 1}`) // 2 | ${ 1 + 1 }
```